# Loop through the files from multible directories as function in bash

Tags: bash

I want to loop through several directories and do something with those files.

Why does the following command only print the files from the last directory I pass as argument but not the ones from the previous arguments? How can I make it work with a loop? I know I could do something like this for example with the `find` command. Thanks!

```sh
list(){ for entry in ${@}*; do   echo "$entry"; done; }

list dir1/ dir2/
```

Comment: `${@}*` only appends the `*` to the _last_ item in `$@`. Also, using `$@` instead of `"$@"` makes it behave just like `$*`, with all the bugs that implies.

Comment: Use `find`, it's designed to do that.

Answer (score 3):

#### Part One: Workaround

Nest your loop -- and add more quotes.

```
list() {
  local arg entry
  for arg in "$@"; do
    for entry in "$arg"*; do
      echo "$entry"
    done
  done
}
```

...though if all you want is to print the matches, this would be better written as:

```
list() { local arg; for arg; do printf '%s\n' "$arg"*; done; }
```

---

#### Part Two: Why

This is normal array expansion behavior. Consider:

```
array=( one two three )
printf '%s\n' "first${array[@]}last"
```

...which has output:

```
firstone
two
threelast
```

**not**, as you seem to expect,

```
firstonelast
firsttwolast
firstthreelast
```

So: An array expansion with a string concatenated to the beginning or end concatenates to the first or last item respectively, *not* to each and every item within that array.

Comment: Thank you! I will defintiely accept your answer. Does this mean something like this wouldn't be possible with bash? Meaning with a `for ...loop` without making my function extremely comlicated?

Comment: I don't agree that this is anything like "extremely complicated". In general, modern shell languages have a legacy of almost 50 years of backwards compatibility to contend with, full of places where the thing that looks simplest and obvious is also _buggy_ in ways that couldn't be fixed without breaking compatibility. If you want to write bug-free code in shell, you need to learn all the pitfalls and the workarounds for that pitfalls; if you don't want to do that, you're better off learning a different / more modern / better-designed language.

Comment: If you _do_ want to learn to write correct shell scripts, [BashPitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) is one good resource; the [BashFAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) another; the [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) a third.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the `loop` inside of your function. This is great. thanks!